# Magnific Popup: Does plugin preload images for small screens?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, magnific-popup, preloading

If the [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin is initialised using a `disableOn` argument and a `preload` argument, will the images preload for window widths smaller than the `disableOn` value?

For example, using the following initialise script, will images preload if the page loads in a window narrower than 720px?

```
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type:'image',
    gallery:{enabled:true},
    disableOn: 720,
    preload: [1,3]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it'll just open raw image, as if user just clicked on link.

You'll need to code this feature manually, if you need it to work with `disableOn` too, take a look how default one is done in souce https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/blob/master/src/js/gallery.js#L137

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry! I wondered because for mobile (i.e. small screen widths) preloading would be undesirable. Seems like it runs as I’d expect.